# Unordered Tree Pattern Matching Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, tree, pattern-matching

I am trying to find a reasonable algorithm find the first tree pattern matching in unordered, rooted trees. According to [some research](https://books.google.ee/books?id=yMTtINqSyWAC&pg=PA150&lpg=PA150&dq=tree%20inclusion%20vs%20pattern%20matching&source=bl&ots=6Yf8nhkQVr&sig=MGFRsbwn8D1UebQeDNQi2IOeUL8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi-86z5q_rVAhWCVRQKHQLzDoEQ6AEIQjAF#v=onepage&q=unordered&f=false) I have come across, this problem is NP-Complete. I don't need to find every pattern match, I just need to find any pattern matching that exists. Preferably, I would rather not have to perform "deletions" on my tree (nor do I want to make a copy to delete nodes from).

Another thing to note is that the tree will be updated between tree matching queries, so I'm also hoping that there may be some algorithms that take advantage of this fact, possibly using an online approach that keeps track of previous partial matches in the tree to optimize a future match.

Is there a straightforward algorithm that can solve this problem given the criteria I mentioned, but one that is still better than the pure naive brute force approach?

Notes, my problem is similar to [this previously asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11376672/partial-subtree-matching-algorithm), but that question is specific to ordered trees.

Comment: What do you mean by "tree matching"?  Is it to figure out when one tree has the same shape as another?  Or is it to figure out when one tree can fit into another one's shape?  Or something else?

Comment: Without thinking *too* hard about it, it seems like this problem will be NP-complete because of the difficulty of deciding which pattern subtree to match to which input subtree when multiple assignments are possible.  There will be a reduction from vertex cover or something.   Maybe there is something about your real life problem that saves you from having to worry about this?

Comment: @btilly I edited my question, I'm referring to tree pattern matching as defined in the intro of the article that I cited in the question.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1570866704000644 the problem that is NP-complete is *tree inclusion*.  That means that the tree can fit in potentially skipping generations.  So, for instance, a tree with one root and 1000 leaves could fit into a tree which branches in 2 10x.  And because this problem is NP-complete, you cannot do fundamentally better exponential growth as the trees grow.

But you can reduce that exponent and do much better than brute force.  For example for each node in the tree record the maximum depth below it and total number of descendants.  As you try to fit one tree into the other, stop searching whenever you're trying to fit a subtree with too much depth or too many children.  This will let you avoid following a lot of lost causes.

You can also use dynamic programming to help.  What you try to do is store for each pair of nodes from the two trees whether or not the subtree below one can be mapped to the other.  When you're looking at whether `a` can go to `b` what you first do is map the children of `a` in to the children of `b`.  If any can't go, then you know that the answer is no.  If all can go, then sort the children of `a` from fitting in the least to the most places.  Now do a brute force search for how to fit the one into the other.  You'll tend to find your dead ends very quickly with this way of organizing the search.

However if the trees are large, if the one won't fit into the other you can spend a very, very long time figuring that fact out.